# Getting "Product Name" from a PE file in Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get the EXE's product name in Linux using Python's pefile:

```py
def _get_product_name(pe, source: str) -> Optional[str]:
    if not hasattr(pe, "VS_VERSIONINFO"):
        return None
    if not hasattr(pe, "FileInfo"):
        return None
    for entry in pe.FileInfo:
        if not hasattr(entry, "StringTable"):
            continue
        for st in entry.StringTable:
            for k, v in st.entries.items():
                if k == "ProductName":
                        return v
    return None
```

I am testing the famous Notepad.exe There is no StringTable. What am I missing?

How do I get the data from the `Details` tab of the `Notepad.exe` file?properties: `File description`, `Type`, `Product name`, `Original filename`.